# Creating duplicate outlets/actions on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uislider, ibaction

I currently have three separate sliders on my `viewcontroller.swift` that I would like to all perform the same function, which is to round the slider value to the nearest position. I have already completed the first one, as such:

```
@IBAction func changePos(_ sender: UISlider) {
    slider.value = roundf(slider.value)
}
```

I have tried many different ways to add the same function to different UISliders by using `slider2, changePos2, etc`, but my app either crashes or doesn't perform the function.

How do I make separate UISliders perform the same function within the same viewcontroller?

Comment: What is the crash says ?

Comment: Change your `func` to use `sender` instead of `slider` and then wire all of your sliders to this one `@IBAction`. `@IBAction func changePos(_ sender: UISlider) {
sender.value = roundf(sender.value)}`

Comment: Okay, I just set all the slider variables to `sender` and everything works properly. So for my other two, I don't have to make a new IBOutlet or IBAction? I can simply put a new func inside of the existing IBAction?

Comment: Problem solved, I used your advice on changing to sender and also implemented `changePos1, changePos2, changePos3` and they all work.

Comment: @jacobbullon That is not at all the proper solution and not what vacawama suggested. You only need the one `changePos` method. Inside it, simply change both references of `slider` to `sender`. Then connect all of your sliders to that one IBAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook all 3 sliders up to the same `@IBAction`. Just use the `sender` parameter instead of your `slider` output in the implementation.

```
@IBAction func changePos(_ sender: UISlider) {
    sender.value = sender.value.rounded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The good way to do this is using IBOutletCollections like below.

```
@IBOutlet var sliders: [UISlider]!
```

and then using nice swift syntax below:

```
sliders.forEach { (slider) in
            slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        }
```

This way you will have same selector get called for each of the sliders.